# Android App: Cannot pass method from another class into the main class

Tags: java, android

Hi there I am fairly new to Android ADK. I am trying to pass the method from the class SETUP which is on seperate file into the main class which is KakaMainActivity. However as soon as the app runs via simulator it crashes right away. Please help!

//KakaMainActivity Class

```
package com.example.kaka;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KakaMainActivity extends Activity {

    Button sendMSG1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send1);
    Button sendMSG2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send2);
    TextView RESULT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_Result);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaka_main);

    SETUP clickAGAIN = new SETUP();
    clickAGAIN.click();
   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.kaka_main, menu);
    return true;
   }

}
```

//SETUP Class

```
package com.example.kaka;

import android.view.View;

public class SETUP extends KakaMainActivity {
    public void click(){
            sendMSG1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){
                        RESULT.setText("First message HELLO WORLD!");
            }
        });

        sendMSG2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                RESULT.setText("Second message BYE BYE");
            }
        }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: A crash is always accompanied with an error report. Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, do you want to launch a new SETUP activity when creating KakaMainActivity?

Comment: why do you need `SETUP` ? Is `KakaMainActivity` not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Several problems...

First, you should not instantiate an `Activity` like this

```
SETUP clickAGAIN = new SETUP();
```

If `SETUP` is only to hold your `onClick()` then you can have it `implements OnClickListener` and not extend any class. [See this answer for help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967569/android-startactivity-from-different-context/18968062#18968062)

Second, you can't try to instantiate `Views` until you have inflated your `layout` with an `inflater` or by calling `setContentView()`. So change your `KakaMainActivity` to

```
Button sendMSG1; // you can declare them here
Button sendMSG2; 
TextView RESULT; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaka_main);

    sendMSG1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send1);  // but initialize them here
    sendMSG2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send2);
    RESULT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_Result);
```

Also, you should change `RESULT` to `result` to conform to Java standards (not necessary but good practice). Right now it looks like a `constant`.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your views after `setContentView`

```
private Button sendMSG1; 
private Button sendMSG2;
private TextView RESULT;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaka_main);
sendMSG1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send1);
sendMSG2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send2);
RESULT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_Result);
sendMSG1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v){
                    RESULT.setText("First message HELLO WORLD!");
        }
    });
sendMSG2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            RESULT.setText("Second message BYE BYE");
        }
    });  
}
```

Also you can add click listeners in this activity itself

Using annonymous inner class

```
  sendMSG1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v){
                    RESULT.setText("First message HELLO WORLD!");
        }
    });
```

Also you have this

```
SETUP clickAGAIN = new SETUP();
clickAGAIN.click();
```

Then

```
public class SETUP extends KakaMainActivity
```

Your instantiating a activity class which you should not do .Activity has a ui and is started by `startActivtiy(new Intent(param))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the UI component after setting up the layout.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaka_main);
sendMSG1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Send1);
...
RESULT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_Result);
```